# A function to run correlations for several variables

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a function to run correlations between several variables, I'm aware that this function doesn't work, but how can I make a function to pick column A and B and run correlation? Any suggestions? Appreciated!

```
q1 <- sample(1:100,10)
q2 <- sample(1:100,10)
q3 <- sample(1:100,10)
q4 <- sample(1:100,10)

df <- data.frame(q1,q2,q3,q4)

pcor <- function(df, method) {
  A <- A,data=df 
  B <- B, data=df 
  partCorr <- Hmisc::rcorr((A), (B), type = method)
  return(list(r=partCorr$r[1,2], p=partCorr$P[1,2], n=partCorr$n[1,2]))
}

name <- character()
r <- p <- n <- numeric()
for (i in 1:4) { 
  for (j in (i+1):4) {
    df <- data.frame(A=df[,i], B=df[,j]) 
    pcorResult <- pcor(df, method='spearman')
    name <- c(name, paste0(colnames(all)[i],'_',colnames(all)[j])) 
    r <- c(r,pcorResult$r)
    p <- c(p,pcorResult$p)
    n <- c(n,pcorResult$n)
  }
}


results <- data.frame(name, r, p, n)
r
```

esults

Comment: @Adam, thanks for you answer! But each itteration is saved and will be presented in one row so I dont think thats the problem. The for loop I have used in other code. My problem is how to make the function to work.

Comment: Oh yeah, brain lock. I see the iteration. Morning reading comprehension is not always the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some small tweaks to make your code work:

- renamed the dataframe you create in the loop to prevent it from overwriting your `df`,
- select the proper columns in the `pcor` function,
- have `i` range to `4-1` because if `i=4`, then the inner for loop becomes `for (j in 5:4)`.

```
q1 <- sample(1:100,10)
q2 <- sample(1:100,10)
q3 <- sample(1:100,10)
q4 <- sample(1:100,10)

df <- data.frame(q1,q2,q3,q4)

pcor <- function(df, method) {
  partCorr <- Hmisc::rcorr(df$A, df$B, type = method)
  return(list(r=partCorr$r[1,2], p=partCorr$P[1,2], n=partCorr$n[1,2]))
}

name <- character()
r <- p <- n <- numeric()
for (i in 1:(4-1)) { 
  for (j in (i+1):4) {
    df2 <- data.frame(A=df[,i], B=df[,j]) 
    pcorResult <- pcor(df2, method='spearman')
    name <- c(name, paste0(colnames(all)[i],'_',colnames(all)[j])) 
    r <- c(r,pcorResult$r)
    p <- c(p,pcorResult$p)
    n <- c(n,pcorResult$n)
  }
}


results <- data.frame(name, r, p, n)
```

Answer (score 0):

With my understanding of your question, won't converting the data.frame to a matrix and using corr.plot solve your purpose